# Workaround for python 2.4's yield not allowed in try block with finally clause

Tags: python, yield, python-2.4, try-finally

I'm stuck on python2.4, so I can't use a finally clause with generators or `yield`.  Is there any way to work around this?

I can't find any mentions of how to work around this limitation in python 2.4, and I'm not a big fan of the workarounds I've thought of (mainly involving `__del__` and trying to make sure it runs within a reasonable time) aren't very appealing.

Comment: Such an old question, while it applies to my current task: « `Python2.4.3 (#1, Oct 23 2012, (...) [GCC 4.1.2 20080704`  » !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can duplicate code to avoid the finally block:

```
try:
  yield 42
finally:
  do_something()
```

Becomes:

```
try:
  yield 42
except:  # bare except, catches *anything*
  do_something()
  raise  # re-raise same exception
do_something()
```

(I've not tried this on Python 2.4, you may have to look at sys.exc_info instead of the [re-raise](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2007/09/12/re-raising-exceptions/) statement above, as in `raise sys.exc_info[0], sys.exc_info[1], sys.exc_info[2]`.)

Answer (score 3):

The only code that's guaranteed to be called when a generator instance is simply abandoned (garbage collected) are the `__del__` methods for its local variables (if no references to those objects exist outside) and the callbacks for weak references to its local variables (ditto).  I recommend the weak reference route because it's non-invasive (you don't need a special class with a `__del__` -- just anything that's weakly referenceable).  E.g.:

```
import weakref

def gen():
  x = set()
  def finis(*_):
    print 'finis!'
  y = weakref.ref(x, finis)
  for i in range(99):
    yield i

for i in gen():
  if i>5: break
```

this does print `finis!`, as desired.

Comment: Was/is it guaranteed in Python that the `y` local variable won't get cleaned up before the `x` local variable? If `y` is garbage collected first, then there is no weakref anymore by the time `x` is garbage collected, and the callback is never called. Of course this is still a great idea, it just requires storing the weak references elsewhere, and maybe extra logic in the weak reference callback to clean up its weak reference after it was called.